# Athena type INT64 in parquet is incompatible with type double defined in table schema

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have converted data from csv to parquet file format using pyspark infer schema and tried to read data using Athena.

```
    df.printSchehma()
    test_num : double (nullable = true)
```

Athena also using double data type when we create table with Glue crawler, we cant query table with below issue.

Error:

```
   test_num : type INT64 in parquet is incompatible with type double defined in table schema
```

Any suggestions to resolve this issue ? appreciate your help.

Comment: You can change the schema column in the table in Glue to INTEGER

Comment: I have tried option, this time I am seeing below error
"type DOUBLE in parquet is incompatible with type int defined in table schema"

Comment: You probably have multiple parquet files with different types for that column. Check the way that you generated these parquet files and verify that they all write the same type.